# SharePoint library sort isn't working for new items

Tags: library, sorting

I have a SharePoint document library where all items uploaded after Feb 9th are not getting sorted with the rest of the items. It doesn't matter what the sort column is.

For example: Sort by Name shows all other docs a-z then the new docs a-z. Sort by Modified By shows all other docs a-z then the new docs a-z. Sort by Modified (date) asc shows all other docs asc then the new docs asc.

But grouping by Name or Modified By sorts correctly.

There are no workflows on this list or any other trickery that I can see. I've created a new view and the same is happening there.

Any ideas for figuring out the cause are appreciated!

Comment: check the view, if you have any filter on it? also try to create a new view with all items and test it

Comment: Hi Waqas, Whether I filter in the view or filter using the column headings, the result is the same. I have created a new view, as mentioned above, and the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This list is suddenly sorting correctly.

I'm guessing that a change at the farm level may have caused the issue and has been corrected.